# Is there an error to this solution regarding planar curves and area calculations

Tags: differential-geometry

I have the following question from a problem sheet, with the answer provided below.

[image]

[image]

For part (b) I am understand what is going on, however, after evaluating the cross product within the norm, how are we able to instead apply the norm onto each part. More specifically why can we do: $$\|\alpha\times\alpha'+rb+r^2\kappa_\alpha\|=\|\alpha\times\alpha'\|+\|rb\|+\|r^2\kappa_\alpha\|.$$

Im assuming that the vector inside the norm has 2 elements so I don't see how the norm can be used like that.

Comment: This solution is utter garbage.  (And you wrote the norm of a scalar as a third term; that wasn't too cool, either.) They dropped one of the four terms and lost a factor of $2$ in the middle term. But you can't distribute norm across a sum, of course.

Comment: I didn't write these solutions. I was only provided them by my lecturer. In a way I'm glad its wrong and I haven't missed something fundamental. Considering It is wrong, have you any hints in how part (b) can be obtained?

Comment: Yes, I knew you hadn't written it because you said "the answer provided below." I would suggest you ask your lecturer to explain it carefully.  I have suggested the two ways I know how to do it as an answer below.

Comment: Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can do a correct proof by parametrizing the region and using a double integral. Alternatively, if you have learned about support lines of a convex curve, an easy proof (see Exercise 8 on p. 32 of [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf)) comes from using the formulas
$$\ell = \int_0^{2\pi} p(\theta)\,d\theta \quad\text{and}\quad A = \frac12\int_0^{2\pi}(p(\theta)^2 - p'(\theta)^2)d\theta.$$
Here $p(\theta)$ is the support function, the distance from the origin to the tangent line to the curve measured perpendicularly along a ray with polar angle $\theta$. (Note that if $p$ is the support function of the original convex curve, then $p+r$ is the support function of the parallel curve.)